# algorithm searching through dictionary

Tags: c#

Im working from the Q https://www.testdome.com/for-developers/solve-question/10282

```
Write a function that, given a list and a target sum, returns zero-based indices of any two distinct elements whose sum is equal to the target sum. If there are no such elements, the function should return null.

For example, FindTwoSum(new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12) should return a Tuple<int, int> containing any of the following pairs of indices:

1 and 4 (3 + 9 = 12)
2 and 3 (5 + 7 = 12)
3 and 2 (7 + 5 = 12)
4 and 1 (9 + 3 = 12)
```

So far iv got:

```
 class TwoSum
           {
               public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
               {
                   //throw new NotImplementedException("Waiting to be implemented.");
                   IList<int> duplicateList = list;

                   foreach (int i in list)
                   {
                       foreach (int j in duplicateList)
                       {
                           if (i != j)
                           {
                               if (i + j == sum)
                               {
                                   return Tuple.Create(i, j);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }

                   return null;
               }

               public static void Main(string[] args)
               {
                   Tuple<int, int> indices = FindTwoSum(new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12);
                   Console.WriteLine(indices.Item1 + " " + indices.Item2);
               }
           }
```

This returns the correct answer in my code but is failing 3 out of 4 cases in the quesitong because:

```
Example case: Wrong answer 
  No solution: Correct answer 
  One solution: Wrong answer 
  Performance test with a large number of elements: Wrong answer
```

Ive looked at the hints

```
    Hint 1: Nested for loops can iterate over the list and calculate a sum in O(N^2) time.

Hint 2: A dictionary can be used to store pre-calculated values, this may allow a solution with O(N) complexity.
```

So im using nested loops but Im guessing in this instance in order to pass hint2 I need to use a dictionary...How can I refactor this into using a dictionary?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You return directly when you find a pair which sum is the desired sum. You should create a temporary collection and add pairs to it and return the said collection after those `foreach`

Comment: If your collection is ordered, you can search from both sides inwards, instead of matching all to each ... but that's a big if :)

Comment: Your question is hard to read. You could replace the code-sections by quote ones, in case you are quoting something.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning indexes, you are returning values. `for` loops are not `foreach` loops.

A nested for loops solution would be something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.Count-1; i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<list.Count;j++)
    {
        if(list[i]+list[j] == sum)
        {
            return Tuple.Create(i, j);
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

I'll leave the dictionary solution for you to create.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this one received 50%

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
        int n = list.Count-1;
        while(n != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count-1 ; i++)
            {
                if (list[n] + list[i] == sum)
                {
                    return Tuple.Create(i, n);
                }
            }
            n--;
        }
        return null;
}
```

// get list value:

```
        var aat = (from l1 in list
                  from l2 in list
                  where l1 + l2 == 12
                  group new { l1, l2} by new { l1, l2 } into gp
                  select new {gp.Key}).ToDictionary( a => a.Key.l1, b => b.Key.l2 );
```

// get list index of the value:

```
        var aav = (from l1 in list
                   from l2 in list
                   where l1 + l2 == 12
                   group new { l1, l2 } by new { l1, l2 } into gp
                   select new { gp.Key })
                   .ToDictionary( a => list.IndexOf(a.Key.l1), b => list.IndexOf(b.Key.l2) 
                   );
```